# Limiting the length of a URL encoded string with multibyte characters in .NET

Tags: .net, urlencode, truncate, multibyte

I am using .NET, and I need to truncate a string that may contain multibyte characters so that it will not be over a set length once it is URL encoded.  This seems like something that would be built in, but I can't find it.

I would just do a substring once it is URL encoded, but that might take off part of a encoded character (space becomes %20, and if it was at the end it could get truncated to %2, which is invalid), or that part of a multibyte character would get truncated (π gets encoded as %CF%80, and it could get truncated as %, %CF, %CF%8, all of which are wrong).

Comment: Are you asking how to truncate a string at a given length, or are you asking how to do it automatically?  The answer the the first question is longString.Substring(0,maxLength).

Comment: @Kendrick: I think the question is that you don't really know how long a string is going to be in its urlencoded form, until you actually urlencode it, since some characters in the original (a.k.a. multibyte characters) will require more than one byte in the urlencoded version.

Comment: @MusiGenesis: That is correct.  I have updated my question to be more specific.

Comment: Nothing you can do but throw an InvalidArgumentException.  You need to get rid of this length limit one way or another if that's not desirable behavior.

Comment: I agree with @Hans Passant, if your truncation will cause a problem (and that seems likely) then you should throw an exception or otherwise warn the user.  You can always accept longer strings and only have to deal with the issue in extreme cases...

Comment: @Hans Passant, @Kendrick Yea, it would probably be bad to blindly truncate what is passed in, but in this case I know the input and the process well enough to know that it isn't going to be an issue.

Comment: If it is not an issue, why did you ask this question?

Comment: I am not worried about the possible effects of truncating the input, but I am worried about having an improperly encoded result, like one that ends with %2

Answer (score 1):

My quick Google search didn't turn up anything for this, which is slightly surprising since this seems like a relatively common problem (at least for those who don't avoid monstrously long URLs).

You could do this iteratively where you encode the string, and if the encoded string is too long you chop a character off the original and re-encode, and keep doing this until the encoded string is short enough.  This would obviously not be very performant.

Comment: But you could do something like a binary search.  Call `Encoding.GetByteCount()`.  If that's too long, subtract half the difference from the string length and try again.  If that fits, then add half the difference, etc.  Although doing it character-by-character is probably "fast enough," considering that this probably won't be done very often.